# Making fixed stepsize and ticks count on y-axis in chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have used `scales.y.ticks.stepsize` and `scales.y.ticks.count` properties to make fixed stepsize and ticks count as per docs but it didn't work.

I required:

`scales.y.ticks.stepsize = 20`

`scales.y.ticks.count = 5`

It works if datasets have large numbers like (50, 90) but not with small numbers (1, 3).

Jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/9r2wf6d4/4/

[image]

Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes to your code so that the scales align more closely with my expectations: a main y-axis that ranges from 0 to 100 with steps of 20, and a secondary y-axis ("total") that ranges from 0 to 5 with steps of 1.

I changed the Y-axis scale configuration as follows

Added explicit `min` and `max` values:

```
min: 0,   // Minimum value
max: 100, // Maximum value
```

Adjusted the `stepSize`:

```
ticks: {
    count: 5,
    beginAtZero: true,
    autoSkip: false, 
    stepSize: 20,
}
```

`total` scale configuration:

```
min: 0,   // Minimum value
max: 5,   // Maximum value
```

Changed the `stepSize` to `1` for consistent monotonic increments:

```
ticks: {
    count: 5,
    autoSkip: false,
    stepSize: 1,
}
```

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["x1", "x2", "x3"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "First",
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: [3, 20, 30],
    barPercentage: 0.3,
  },
  {
    label: "Second",
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: [3, 7, 9],
    barPercentage: 0.3,
  },
  {
    label: "Third",
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: [3, 3, 3],
    barPercentage: 0.5,
    yAxisID: "total"
  }]
};

var options = {
  toolbar: {
      show: false
  },
  fill: {
    type: "gradient",
    gradient: {
      shadeIntensity: 1,
      opacityFrom: 0.5,
      opacityTo: 0.5,
      stops: [0, 100]
    }
  },
 scales: {
    x: {
      stacked: true,
      barThickness: 30,
    }, 
    y: {
      min: 0,   // Minimum value
      max: 100, // Maximum value
      stacked: true,
      ticks: {
        count: 5,
        beginAtZero: true,
        autoSkip: false, 
        stepSize: 20,
      },
      grid: {
        drawBorder: false
      }
    },
    total: {
      min: 0,   // Minimum value
      max: 5,   // Maximum value
      display: true,
      ticks: {
        count: 5,
        autoSkip: false,
        stepSize: 1,
      },
      beginAtZero: true,
      position: 'right',
    }
}

};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>


<canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="100"></canvas>
```